# why my Django project doesn't work?

Tags: django

I have a simple Django project in which I have to show a graph of dots . I faced two problems : the first is that  my html file on windows works correctly but on ubuntu  it shows only  the head of the page. The secoond problem is when I runserver even when the html fole is empty I get page not found 404 . These  are files that I have worked on  and print screen of the web's result:

templates/aps/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <meta http-equip="refresh" content ="3">
    </head>
 <body>

  <h3>Valeurs enregistrés par notre capteur de temperature<h3> 



 <canvas id="graph"></canvas>
 <script>
  var graph;
  var xPadding = 40;
  var yPadding = 30;

        // Notice I changed The X values

             var data = { values:[
               { X: 0, Y: 16 },
               { X: 3, Y: 28 },
               { X: 6, Y: 18 },
               { X: 9, Y: 34 },
               { X: 12, Y: 40 },
               { X: 15, Y: 80 },
               { X: 18, Y: 60 }
            ]};

            // Returns the max Y value in our data list
            function getMaxY() {
                var max = 0;

                for(var i = 0; i < data.values.length; i ++) {
                    if(data.values[i].Y > max) {
                        max = data.values[i].Y;
                    }
                }

                max += 10 - max % 10;
                return max;
            }

            // Returns the max X value in our data list
            function getMaxX() {
                var max = 0;

                for(var i = 0; i < data.values.length; i ++) {
                    if(data.values[i].X > max) {
                        max = data.values[i].X;
                    }
                }

                max += 10 - max % 10;
                return max;
            }

            // Return the x pixel for a graph point
            function getXPixel(val) {
                // uses the getMaxX() function
                return ((graph.width - xPadding) / getMaxX()) * val + (xPadding * 1.5);
            }

            // Return the y pixel for a graph point
            function getYPixel(val) {
                return graph.height - (((graph.height - yPadding) / getMaxY()) * val) - yPadding;
            }

                graph = document.getElementById("graph");
                var c = graph.getContext('2d');            

                c.lineWidth = 2;
                c.strokeStyle = '#333';
                c.font = 'italic 8pt sans-serif';
                c.textAlign = "center";

                // Draw the axises
                c.beginPath();
                c.moveTo(xPadding, 0);
                c.lineTo(xPadding, graph.height - yPadding);
                c.lineTo(graph.width, graph.height - yPadding);
                c.stroke();

                // Draw the X value texts
                for(var i = 0; i < data.values.length; i ++) {
                    // uses data.values[i].X
                    c.fillText(data.values[i].X, getXPixel(data.values[i].X), graph.height - yPadding + 20);
                }

                // Draw the Y value texts
                c.textAlign = "right"
                c.textBaseline = "middle";

                for(var i = 0; i < getMaxY(); i += 10) {
                    c.fillText(i, xPadding - 10, getYPixel(i));
                }

                c.strokeStyle = '#f00';

                // Draw the line graph
                c.beginPath();
                c.moveTo(getXPixel(data.values[0].X), getYPixel(data.values[0].Y));
                for(var i = 1; i < data.values.length; i ++) {
                   // c.lineTo(getXPixel(data.values[i].X), getYPixel(data.values[i].Y));
                }
                c.stroke();

                // Draw the dots
                c.fillStyle = '#333';

                for(var i = 0; i < data.values.length; i ++) {  
                    c.beginPath();
                    c.arc(getXPixel(data.values[i].X), getYPixel(data.values[i].Y), 4, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
                    c.fill();
                }
</script> 

</body>
</html>
```

view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
context = {}
return render(request, 'aps/index.html', context)
```

newsite/aps/url.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

 urlpatterns = [
 url(r'^$', views.index, name='index')
 ]
```

newsite/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from aps import views

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),    
url(r'^aps/', include('aps.urls')), 
]
```

[image: http://127.0.0.1:8000/]

Comment: Where do you call the url? What have you researched/tried so far?

Comment: I called the url in View.py

Comment: You reference the *template* in the view. You're not calling the url there.

Comment: so how can I call it and where?

Comment: Exactly as Daniel Roseman's answer shows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you for your answer the problem was in the views.py it should be

```
from django.shortcuts import render
def index(request):
  return render(request, 'aps/index.html', {})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your index page is at /aps/, not at /.

However I'm not sure why you are using Django at all, since all you are doing is serving a static HTML page with some Javascript.

Comment: It also doesn't work !! I am working with django because I have to learn it in order to make a whole project and i am in the begining

Comment: Template does not exist at /aps/

Comment: in the future nchalah I will use dynamic data

Answer (score 0):

You need to add something extra in your urls if you

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from aps import views

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^/', include('aps.urls')), 
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),    
url(r'^aps/', include('aps.urls')), 
]
```

this way you will have something on your entry path and it will not crash.
To avoid the crashing page (but this is not for now) you should also have in your settings
       `Debug=False`

Comment: can you send a screenshot of your error or upload your code on github and share a link?